# Which shashtra mention about bhoota pichahsa and other negative energies in detail?

Tags: death, rebirth, evil, ghosts

In `Bhagvadgita` and other popular shashtra like `garuda puran` there is a mention of life after death and `bhooth yooni`, `pichisha yoni`.

Is there any text/Shastra which explains about.

- How a person is captured/forces to enter some other living one's body after death, specially after the death of unmarried ones.
- How a person is freed from bhoota/pichasha yoni.

Answer (score 2):

After some some research i have found a text named `Bhoot Damar Shashtra` which answers first question.

For Second question, `bhagvada geeta` says alot.

There is another text which answers first question, the text is named as `Uddish tantra`.

Both Bhoot Damar and Uddish tantra have been taught by Shiva to Mata Parvati and Ravan respectively.

**Source for first question**: For controlling dead one, there is a method given specially for getting things from Bhootini(the female who enters the bhoota yooni), please note that boota, pichasha are different.
[image: Bhoota damar tantra, chapter 9]
https://archive.org/details/BhutaDamaraTantraS.NKhandelval_201810/page/n59/mode/2up?view=theater

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Explain your answer, say what the texts say about the question with necessary slokas and its menaing

Comment: Good answer. Upvoted!! But As user shashaank ji has told..Please elaborate more in your answer...Moreover where did you learn that Lord Shiva has taught that tantra to Ravana...Please give the sources and verify every info. so that less knowledgeable people like me can also research and get to know about these. 

Comment: I am compiling the quotes from these two texts, will add them soon.